# Prevent Menu Shortcode From Formatting

Tags: menus, shortcode

I'm trying to insert shortcodes into menu links (as I need to display a latest post link). I've figured out how to get the do_shortcode part done.
  However, when I insert a shortcode as the menu link [latest_posts var="val"], it immediately gets formatted like so http:(forward-slash forward-slash)latest_postsvar=val. I'm using 3.5.1, and I was wondering what is the filter/action I can use to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but most of the time, a good way to disable shortcode, e.g in posts is to double [ like this :

```
[[shortcode]]
```

Hopefully this will work in this context.

Comment: Just tried it, still end up like the formatted string :(